# Recuperar valor de um HTTP query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, querystring

Tenho uma URL onde retorna um  HTTP `QueryString`, e necessito recuperar as informações da URL e converter em variáveis para fazer consultas no banco de dados. 
Em PHP basta utilizar o `$_GET[""]`, agora em C# eu não sei como proceder.

Vou dar um exemplo para esclarecer melhor.

Possuo a URL: `http://html.net/page.php?name=Joe&age=12`

Tenho que pegar os valores "Joe" e "12" para uma consulta posterior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimente isso e veja se resolve.

```
string nome = Request.QueryString["name"];

string idade = Request.QueryString["age"];
```

Comment: Não esquece de verificar se o parametro está nulo antes de usar e não use parametros sensíveis na query string. Ex: login, senha, id de usuário logado, session, qualquer parametro de controle que possa ser usado para assumir uma sessao sem necessariamente conhecer algum login.

Comment: Adicionei este código em meu controller, mas ao chamar a página, a variável null.

Comment: public ActionResult Dependente()
        {
            string nome = Request.QueryString["name"];
            var dependente =
                dependenteRepository.Dependentes.Where(r => r.NmPessoa == nome).ToList();
            return View(dependente);

        }

E estou tentando recuperar o valor desta URL:
http://localhost/Usuario/Dependente?name=joao

Comment: Deu certo, esqueci de colocar os parâmetros em meu controller. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Eu tenho que colocar a quantidade de parâmetros que receberei em minha Query String em meu controller, correto?